# new and malloc(C++) failed to allocate memory. How to fix/reallocate?

Tags: c++

I am dealing with the failure of `new` at runtime when the program still needs memory. I do not want the program to stop. So Is there anyway to reallocate? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your program really need more memory than is available on your machine? If it does, it's pretty hard to proceed if you can't get more, and if it doesn't actually need it, maybe you don't actually have to run into the failure of `new`.

Comment: It depends how much additional memory you need (will a fixed amount do?), and whether it is possible to free any existing allocation. This situation is unusual because most modern operating systems overcommit memory, which usually results the system gradually slowing to a halt, and even crashing before `throw bad_alloc` can happen.

Comment: Is your program using memory efficiently? Is it possible for the program to put some of the data in the file (well before the out-of-memory error) so that it uses less memory? Have you checked your program for memory leaks?

Comment: It is not remotely difficult to tell what is being asked here hence my vote to re-open.

Comment: @Troubadour: Do you have a better answer than provided ones?

Comment: @Troubadour: I'd say the question is clear but it remains impossible to answer unless and until the OP provides some more information about the nature of the systems he is running on the task he is tying to complete and how sure he is that he's managing memory correctly in other parts of his task.

Answer (score 2):

You could try temporarily storing objects to disk when they are not needed and reload them when you need to access them. For example Photoshop used to have it's own swap file IIRC. However rolling your own file based object store is not easy - not sure if there are some suitable implementation already out there.

On the other hand in the way you asked the question it seems that you run out of memory unexpectedly - so you might already have some kind of problem in your application design and trying to fix the sympton rather than the cause is not necessarily the best course of action.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide more details.

From the description you have given, I assume your programs throws memory allocation error.
Follow this pattern for at least a graceful exit in out of memory situation.

1. before program starts reserve some memory.
   char reserveMemory = new char[1024 * 1024 ] //1Mb
2. Write a function to release this memory in case of out of memory and set it as the new_handler (check set_new_handler() in a good c++ book).
3. After you have released the reserveMemory, you have 1 Mb of memory on heap. It is up to your skills to utilize this memory to exit gracefully or recover more memory by releasing unwanted objects on heap, etc, etc..

Comment: Would have been better as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could reserve a large static memory block for emergency purposes right at the beginning

```
FixedMemory<1024> fMem(4); // memsize 1024Char 
FixedHeap<1024,16> fHeap(fMem); // 1KiB/ 16Byte = 64 Blocks

// if usual allocation fails:
ptr = (ptrdiff_t) fHeap.alloc(16);// sizeof(Foo)
Foo* foo = new (ptr) Foo ();   
// make sure that Foo does not call new/malloc/...
// or you have to handle that as well
foo->~Foo;
fHeap.free(pMem);
```

Of course, then you have to implement your own memory management. You write your own Heap class with the following interface:

```
class Heap {
protected:
    /** Initializes reference to system memory.*/
    Heap(Memory& memory) : memory(memory)
    {
    }

public:
    /** Allocate a piece of memory.
     * @param size size of the memory to allocate
     * @return pointer to allocated memory or null on error
     */
    virtual void* alloc(size_t size)=0;

    /** Free previously allocated memory.
     * @param p pointer to the memory to free
     */
    virtual void free(void* address)=0;

private:
    /** Reference to the system memory source. */
    Memory& memory;
};
```

The easiest implementation would be a fixed Heap, which only returns pointer segmens of a fixed length (or null pointer, if you try to get more). This is okay, if you already know the maxmimum size you'll need to allocate (`sizeof(ClassToWorkWith)`).

Then you need your fixed Memory:

```
template<size_t MEMSIZE>
class FixedMemory {
private:
    char MemArray[MEMSIZE];
    const size_t alignment;    
public:
    FixedMemory(size_t alignment) :  alignment(alignment)
    {
    }

    void * GetMemory()
    {
        return  (void*)((char*)MemArray);
    }
};
```

Then you can implement a Fixed Heap basically like this

```
template<size_t MEMSIZE, size_t BLOCKSIZE>
class FixedHeap : public Heap {
private:
    void *FreeHead;
    size_t realBlockSize;

public:
    FixedHeap(Memory& memory) : Heap(memory), FreeHead(0)
    {
            realBlockSize = BLOCKSIZE;
            if(memory.alignment < sizeof(void*))return;
            if(realBlockSize < sizeof(void*))realBlockSize = sizeof(void*);
            realBlockSize += (BLOCKSIZE%memory.alignment) ? (memory.alignment - BLOCKSIZE%memory.alignment) : 0;
            if( MEMSIZE >= realBlockSize ) {
                    char *pMemory = (char *)memory.GetMemory();
                    size_t malAlignment = (memory.alignment - (size_t)pMemory%memory.alignment)%memory.alignment;
                    size_t actualMemSize = MEMSIZE - malAlignment;
                    pMemory += malAlignment;

                    for(size_t i=0; i<actualMemSize/realBlockSize-1; i++)
                    {
                            *((ptrdiff_t *)(&pMemory[i*realBlockSize])) = (ptrdiff_t)&pMemory[(i+1)*realBlockSize];
                    }

                    *((ptrdiff_t *)(&pMemory[(actualMemSize/realBlockSize-1)*realBlockSize])) = 0;
                    FreeHead = (void *)pMemory;
            }
    }

    void* alloc(size_t size)
    {
            if( size > BLOCKSIZE || !FreeHead ) return 0;
            void *Result = FreeHead;
            FreeHead = (void *)*((ptrdiff_t *)FreeHead);
            return Result;
    }

    void free(void* address)
    {
            if( address && (! address % realBlockSize)) {
                    *((ptrdiff_t *)address) = (ptrdiff_t)FreeHead;
                    FreeHead = address;
            }
    }
};
```

There are several better alternatives, like `FirstFitHeap` but I just wanted to give you a hint.

Comment: Could you explain more ?